# FB.ui() fbml.dialog — Hangs

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm working on a Facebook (canvas) app where I'd like to show the user a FB-style dialog box. I'm trying to do this with `FB.ui()`, using the `fbml.dialog` method. My every attempt at this today has yielded a dialog box that shows loading bars, but nothing ever happens.

Subscribing to log events shows nothing.

The code below is the simplest version I've tried, and is lifted straight from Facebook's sample code, which I've seen working (http://fbrell.com/fb.ui/fbml.dialog).

```
function sendToFriends(){
    var dialog = {
        method: 'fbml.dialog',
        display: 'dialog',
        fbml: '<fb:header icon="false" decoration="add_border">Hello World!</fb:header><fb:profile-pic uid="5526183"></fb:profile-pic>'
    };
    FB.ui(dialog, function(response){alert(response);});
}
```

As usual, Facebook's documentation is incomplete and all over the place. I'd appreciate any help you could offer.

Comment: can you post your IFrame page that contains this script? also check in firebug for errors...I've just tried the code u posted and it's working just fine

Comment: Seems like you are trying out on your local machine! to use display:dialog, you must be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question lies probably in a buggy behaviour as documented here
[FB.ui dialog for apprequest hangs forever in iframe mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156145/fb-ui-dialog-for-apprequest-hangs-forever-in-iframe-mode)

Did you try the popup mode already? Maybe this temporarily fixes the issue. Hopefully there will be a fix in the facebook api soon.

Comment: hmmm, probably I am a little late with my answer :) But maybe someone can make use of the link to the other thread....

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered elsewhere on stackoverflow, but I can't remember where; actually I was searching for it when I found this question.

Very approximately, you need to construct your html, put it somewhere inside the JS library for facebook (I can't remember where: possibly as a user-created element of XFBML or something), and THEN call the dialog box.

It's complicated. If I find the post I was looking for, I'll link to it here.

Comment: Thanks. Here's hoping one of us finds it…