# FB.ui dialog for apprequest hangs forever in iframe mode

Tags: javascript, facebook

Somehow I can't get the iframe mode to work in the following code 
The dialog shows up but the loading hangs forever and nothing is displayed in the box
it works just fine with display: popup

```
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(resp) {

      if (resp.status !== 'connected') return;
      FB.ui({
        method: 'apprequests',
        title: 'My title',
        display: 'iframe',
        message: 'My message',
        to: '100003750613973'
      }, function(resp) {
        console.log('emitted request to ', resp.to);
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Myself and some of my peers are seeing the same behavior. In our case, the problem seems to happen only when running on a port other than 80. E.g. in development, we usually run on port 3000, and see the hang you describe (with the "feed" dialog in our case). When running on port 80, everything works fine. This appears to be a recent problem.

Comment: Hopefully that should be it, I ll try it out and confirm you asap

Comment: Thks a lot that was it. Is this documented somewhere on facebook ?

Comment: Someone else filed this bug, and I left some comments on it, also referencing this question. http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/336905163037731

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used FB.ui in quite a while so not sure how it changed meanwhile, but why do you return console.log()? I'd say, remove the return keyword and try again. See what the Firbug / Chrome / etc. console says. Based on that I'm sure you'll be able to get to a working solution, or post it here and we can help you out. Code should be quite standard.

Comment: This is just some coffeescript I quickly translated to JS. Thing is the callback is only called when the dialog is closed so this code is not even reached unless I manually close the dialog box.

Comment: Also this code works just fine if I replace 'iframe' by 'popup'

Comment: I know that code only runs only if the dialog is open, but it's JS so you shouldn't think like that because an error somewhere else in the code can cause problems you wouldn't expect (not the case here though).

DO you have a link? No warnings/errors in the console?